# Determine which process captures a global hotkey in OS X

Tags: swift, macos, debugging, hotkeys

Some time ago, the global hotkey I had reserved for Alfred (opt+space) also started switching to the previous application (without showing the application switcher), in addition to launching the Alfred window. I haven't bee able to track down what is causing this behavior.

I have

- ensured that none of my System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts use alt+Space
- disabled everything in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility
- quit Alfred, Divvy, Keyboard Maestro (Engine) i.e. programs I assume could be responsible
- used KeyCue and CheatSheet to see the available app-specific/global hotkeys
- tried a standard US keyboard layout (I'm usually using a non-US keyboard layout, which I have tweaked with Ukulele)

but still opt+Space switches to the previous application. It's not in the [Mac keyboard shortcuts list](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236).

Would any program be able to listen for a particular global hotkey, and if so, would it need permission to control the computer (in the Privacy preferences pane) to switch to the previous application? In that case, is my only choice to start terminating processes and see if the behavior persists? Or is it some quirk in the OS and I have to go through some config files?

Right now I've just assigned a new hotkey for Alfred, but I'd like to know what's the best approach to debugging hotkeys. This isn't the first time I press a key combination and something happens, but I'm unsure what caused or how to reconfigure it.

I appreciate any advice or suggested reading material.